# Keeping scroll distance from top of page despite window height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am changing the background color of my page based on the scroll position from the top of the page, but I want to cycle through all of the colors regardless of of the height of the window. What I have now is strictly based on the number of pixels the scroll is from the top of the page, but you'll see that is dependent on the window height. How could I modify this to get it to always scroll through all of the colors, even if the browser is resized?

What I have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/keith/P7ER3/

Answer (score 1):

This is the documents height: `$(document).height()`

And this is the heipt of the viewport: `$(window).height()`

The difference of both values returns the maximum number of pixels that can be scrolled down (if positive):

```
var max_scroll = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
```

Finally this will return a nuber between 0 and 1 that reflects the scroll-amount:

```
var scrollamount;
if (max_scroll > 0.0) {
    scrollamount = $(document).scrollTop() / max_scroll;
} else {
    scrollamount = 0.0;
}
```

you can use this scrollamount, that allways will be between 0 and 1 to calculare a new color from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `percent difference` between the `window.outerHeight` and `window.pageYOffset`.

```
  window.outerHeight // the pixel height of the browser's frame.

  window.innerHeight // the pixel height of the document within the browser's frame.

  window.pageYOffset  // reflects the current vertical pixel 
                      // location of the top-left corner of the document.
```

---

```
  var perDiff = window.pageYOffset / (window.outerHeight + window.innerHeight);  

  perDiff; // 0 when the scroll is on the top

  perDiff; // 1 when the scroll is on the bottom of the page
```

Instead of `position`, you can use `perDiff` value, that always will be between 0 and 1 to calculate a new color from it.

P.S. in jsfiddle this code is not suppose to work because perDiff refers to the height of the document and not to the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
scroll_pos = $(document).scrollTop();
```

to this:

```
scroll_pos = $(document).scrollTop() % 800;
```

Taking the position modulo 800 will basically reset it back to zero when you scroll beyond 800px.